# Unable to open VBA editor in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin

It's been four years since I started using Outlook VBA Macros. I have never had this issue before. Since yesterday (9/26/2023), I have been unable to open the VBA editor in my Outlook. It even gets stuck when I try to insert a new module.

[image: VBA Editor is not opening]

Already tried:

1. Safe mode
2. Restart computer
3. Create new email profile.
4. Repair and reinstall Office.
5. Checked the VBA add-in

I want to insert new VBA Module and open VBA editor in my Outlook.

Comment: Try this: From the `Window` pulldown at the top... select `Cascade` (after double clicking on one of the modules to make sure it's open)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a little while ago.  Turned out to be a problem in my "With Events" code in ThisOutlookSession.  To fix it, I had to go to Trust Center Settings and check "Disable All Macros Without Notification."  Then, when I restarted Outlook I was able to see my VBA code.  From there, I commented out everything in ThisOutlookSession, and then I went back to the Trust Center and allowed the macros to run again.  After restarting, I started to uncomment the macros in ThisOutlookSession one at a time until I found the one causing the problem and fixed it.